# UITableView in popover measure and set minimum width

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, ios7, uipopovercontroller

I have some popover with a table inside. Table contains default cells with some titles `cell=[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle: UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier: someIdentifier]` (no accessories).

Now i need to make popover as small as possible and do not clip text (no ellipsis). Height is not a problem it is easy to fetch. I have problem with width. Previously I just measured the size of texts from table (`[text sizeWithFont: font].width`) by selecting  the longest and added 20 points to result width and it was ok.
Now in iOS7 this fails since cell is bit different and ellipsis is shown for the longest text.

Is there a good way to detect table (table cell) width? I've tried with `[cell sizeToFit: someBigSize]` but this always returns `width=320`. I've tried this hoping that I will become resistant to iOS changes.

Or is there a specification about table cells and its layout (text margins and so on), I didn't managed to find anything useful.

Worst case scenario I could manually figure out what is proper value to be added to maximum text width, but I prefer some documentation for that.